# Rails - Having a default value for autocomplete field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I'm trying to have a default value show up on my autocomplete_field while allowing users to also look up other options from the same field.

I have tried something like the following as suggested by other posts, by setting the :value as the value that I want as the default; however, it won't pass the validations.

`<%= f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path, :value => current_user.name %>`

Gem: 
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: What kind of validations do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean something in your input box/form field, you could use placeholder: 'value'.

`f.input :brand_name, placeholder: 'Some value', value: 'Some value'`

or

`f.input :brand_name, placeholder: "#{some dynamic value}", value: "#{some dynamic value}"`

This does assume that the f.autocomplete_field method extends/has the same options available as the standard f.input does.

Comment: Hmm I think f.autocomplete works in a different way. I know that having value: " something" should work but it doesn't seem to work that way. Thanks though!